# Discord Bot Needing to Read Webhook Instead of User Message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so my discord bot is set up to find specific keywords in messages and then ping a role in my server. Example:

> keyword = "pizza"
>
> User messages --> My favorite kind of food is pizza and sushi
>
> Bot messages --> @Role

However the issue is that I need the bot to find that specific keyword in a webhook, and I was wondering how I would go about doing this. I've already tried looking through different ways to read embeds, and don't seem to have any luck so just figured I would ask straight up for some help. I've posted the current code that I'm using in this segment. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if (message.channel.id == channel_id):
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
      if keywords[i] in message.content:
          await message.channel.send("<@&role_id>")
```

Answer (score 0):

If a message is sent by a webhook, the `webhook_id` attribute will not be `None`

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.webhook_id is not None:  # if the message is sent by a webhook
        if (message.channel.id == channel_id):
            for i in range(len(keywords)):
                if keywords[i] in message.content:
                    await message.channel.send("<@&role_id>")
```